# A warning on power pins of MCUs, explanation?

Tags: microcontroller

I came across with this warning:

> Most Chinese development boards do not have any kind of protection on
>   the +5V rail. This means that the +5V pin of the USB connector is
>   directly connected to any +5V/VIN pin on the development board. Always
>   check if this is the case when you’re connecting your development
>   board to an external power source while using the USB port.

I could not understand fully that what is the danger? What will be the consequences of this action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you connect two 5V sources together, they fight each other since no two 5V sources are identical. What happens if your computer's USB is 5.1V and your external power source is 4.9V? They cancel out leaving you with 0.2V across a short-circuit across

Comment: how come parallel connection of batteries exist then?

Comment: Batteries aren't regulators. Batteries don't try and regulate their output voltages and can balance their charge between the two so their voltages eventually become equal and track each other. Still, if two batteries are a different enough voltage and you connect them in in parallel, enough current can flow while they re-balance that bad things will happen. Regulators just try to keep their at the output voltage at their desired level at any cost.

Comment: damn mobile phones...

Comment: @muyustan Superior desktops

Comment: so, my laptop's usb output and the external power supply which could cause problems have regulators with them, right?

Comment: @muyustan Yes. Placing a small series resistor can help this. A so-called current balancing resistor. It gives something for the voltage difference to be dropped across rather than just the very low wire resistance which would result in very high currents. Of course, this has it's disadvantages. Maybe between 0.5~1 Ohms for the voltage difference and current levels you might expect from USB.

Comment: OK, thanks, let's wait 6 more minutes for green tick.